# Action Bar location issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar

I have added Action Bar to my application.

For some strange reason on my Galaxy Nexus the over flow menu appears at the bottom of the screen whereas in the stock apps (Maps, Gmail, Google Play, Calendar, etc) the over flow menu appears at the top of the screen.

[image: Overflow at the bottom]

Is there anyway to force it to appear at the top of the screen along with app title?

Note: the top grey bar contains title of my app but I have removed it for this screenshot.

Comment: This isn't going to be helpful, but i recommend using ActionBarSherlock.com instead of the native action bar for better backwards compatibility with non-ICS apps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have yet to consider backwards compatibility with non-ICS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the folks in comments have said, if you plan to go public with your app, you will end up having to acquiesce and use ABS, even if it's not a perfect solution (it's dang close, though). But, to your more immediate problems with ActionBar - try adding these lines to your root menu in XML:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Make sure

```
uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

is not present anywhere in your Android Manifest. You could also test to see if

```
setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true/false) and setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true/false)
```

have any effect on the location of your menu indirectly.

EDIT~ Also, are you using anything along the lines of tabs or other items in your action bar that just aren't showing up but are actually present on the top bar?

EDIT2~ Here's my options menu code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.demographics:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, demoPanel.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.settings:
        // another startActivity, this is for item with id "menu_item2"
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The top bar has nothing but the name of the app. Normally I hide the top bar but I have to display it for Action Bar to work.

Comment: @mob1lejunkie yeah, I understand you have to show it. I had a similar thing happen in my app when it was at the earlier stages, but I don't remember the circumstances that led to the menu button showing up in a second top row rather than the bottom. I just tested my app, splittingwhennarrow leads to my menu icon disappearing entirely - as the top row is filled to the brim with tabs. I'll edit my comment so you can see what my options menu code looks like, maybe it will help.

Comment: Turns out I somehow had uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" which is why over flow menu was being displayed at the bottom.